# Is Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 released?

Tags: visual-studio

My question could be weird, but if you want to download VS Ide the webpage prompts you to VS2019, ok.
But under the blue download button (Community, Professional, IDE), there is a link to download the **preview**. Actually, both links prompt you to the same page.
What does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But under the blue download button (Community, Professional, IDE), there is a link to download the preview.

Visual Studio 2019 was released on April 2nd 2019.  It has received several patches since that date.  The current release build is 16.0.3

Source: [Visual Studio 2019 16.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#GA)

> But under the blue download button (Community, Professional, IDE), there is a link to download the preview.

The current preview build is [16.1 Preview 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-preview#16.1_Preview2)

> What does that mean?

It means you are confused by a preview build of the next major update and the current stable build.